# Writing doubly-recursive functions without pattern matching

Tags: haskell, recursion

The `merge` function used in merge sort can be defined like:

```
merge a@(x:xs) b@(y:ys) | x < y     = x : merge xs  b
                        | otherwise = y : merge a  ys
merge [] b = b
merge a [] = a
```

The function just generates the result by taking the head of the list for which the test condition of being relatively small is "more true", where it is false for the non-existing head of an empty list, and both lists are only traversed once. So it should be possible to use a general iterating function and to subsume the two execution paths given by the `x < y` predicate into one, so that the function reads more like my English description in my first sentence. How would I do that?

Although the `merge` function already is perfectly readable as is, I sometimes find doubly-recursive functions difficult to write, so I'd be happy to learn about more approaches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find your english description pretty incomprehensible, honestly.  *'for which the test condition ... is "more true"'* -- what?  But I'll try, because I enjoy toying with phrasing.   First we need a way to express "where it is false for the non-existing head of an empty list".  What comes to me for that is that we need a data type like `Maybe` but for which the "nothing" case is "infinitely large".  The following will do:

```
data AdjInf a = Finite a | Infinite
    deriving (Eq, Ord)
```

(Just like `Maybe` but with the constructor order reversed -- `Ord` deriving takes care of the rest!)

And we can get the head of a list in terms of this:

```
head' :: [a] -> AdjInf a
head' [] = Infinite
head' (x:xs) = Finite x
```

So now we have:

```
merge :: (Ord a) => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
merge [] [] = []
merge xs ys = next : merge smaller bigger
    where
    (next : smaller, bigger)
        | head' xs <= head' ys = (xs, ys)
        | otherwise            = (ys, xs)
```

Which might meet your criteria.  (This recursion pattern is a list *anamorphism*, so you could write it with [`unfoldr`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:unfoldr))

I would avoid this particular implementation because the fact that the `next : smaller` pattern match will always succeed is quite subtle.   It is also not *quite* the same function if the lists contain distinct elements that compare equal (that is, this `merge` is not "stable").

Comment: Thanks, that's indeed what I meant. Why did you choose the name AdjInf?

Comment: @rubystallion "adjoin infinity" -- maybe `AddInf` could have also worked, I may be abusing the term "adjoin"

Comment: Fun fact, `merge` is parametric in `head'` -- we could take `f :: [a] -> b` (where `Ord b`) as a comparator.  I think we'd get something cool if we require that `f (tail xs) >= f xs`.

Comment: I think fulfilling that requirement with unchanged semantics would also mean that `f (tail xs)` is only necessarily strictly greater than `f xs` if `null (tail xs)`, same as with `AdjInf`, wouldn't it? And if `f` produces an `Ord`, which first compares length and then compares heads, then `merge` would just take all elements from the shorter list before taking from the other list.

Comment: If you didn't want to define your own data type, you could implement `AdjInf` using `Data.Ord.Down`. `AdjInf a` has the same ordering as `Down (Maybe (Down a))`.

Answer (score 3):

You could split the pattern matching in two:

```
merge (a:as) bs = loop bs where
  loop (b:bs) | b < a = b : loop bs
  loop bs             = a : merge as bs
merge [] bs = bs
```

which could also be expressed using `span`

```
merge (a:as) bs = lts ++ a : merge as ges
  where (lts, ges) = span (<a) bs
merge [] bs = bs
```

Answer (score 2):

You could make a single recursive call with different parameters depending on the result of the test.

```
merge xxs@(x:xs) yys@(y:ys) =
    let (z, xs', ys') = if x <= y then (x, xs, yys) else (y, xxs, ys)
    in z : merge xs' ys'
merge [] ys = ys
merge xs [] = xs
```

PS, I wouldn't call your `merge` doubly recursive. Every code path has at most one recursive call.